# Display information from another list based on a lookup column connection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

In my List SharePoint, I two lookUP item.
When I add element to my list, I want to display other information with the lookup.
This is my list:

[image]

any ideas how can I dot it without Visualstudio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this article http://sharepointsps.blogspot.com/2012/11/spdisplayrelatedinfo-in-sp-2010-jquery.html and it wroks fine for me